# Converting between date/time formats in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am working with a web service that returns date/times in OData v4 Format. That format looks like this: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ`. This means the current time would be returned as: "2016-05-11T03:08:00Z".

I have received this date in some client-side JavaScript. I am trying to format the date using the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) library. From my understanding, that library looks for an [ISO 8601 formatted string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

My question is, how do I convert the OData v4 string that I get into an ISO 8601 formatted string? Or, how do I just load the OData v4 string into a `moment` object? My biggest issue seems to be with time zones. For example: If I have

```
2016-06-01T00:00:00Z
```

then use

```
moment('2016-06-01T00:00:00Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

I get

```
05/31/2016
```

However, I was expected `06-01-2016`

Thanks!

Comment: What's your time zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is interpret this UTC date as local time, there is no need to bring in Moment timezone. Just ignore the `z` token.

```
 moment('2016-06-01T00:00:00Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss').format()
 "2016-06-01T00:00:00-05:00" //interpreted as -5 because my browser is central
```

Note that `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` has very limited browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/resolvedOptions

If you do need the time zone information from the browser for some purpose (keep in mind that you don't need this if you only mean the browser's local time), you could use `moment.tz.guess()`. This will use the international API if it is there, and fall back to a heuristic to guess timezone if it is not. http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/

For good measure, if you wish to interpret that date as UTC and display it as UTC, you can use the utc function:

```
moment.utc('2016-06-01T00:00:00Z').format()
"2016-06-01T00:00:00Z" //z for UTC, but displayed with expected date and time
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually handle that by adding timezone offset or  if you can add another dependency `moment timezones js` then you can do something.

```
var tz = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
moment('2016-06-01T00:00:00Z').tz(tz).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

if you know your timezone then simply pass your timezone name.

```
moment('2016-06-01T00:00:00Z').tz('America/New_York').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: Nice. Hadn't ever gone with `Intl`. Will now.